# How do I generate a control flow of an AST (represented in XML) using Python?

Tags: java, python, xml, static-analysis, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the AST of WHILE language(http://www.program-analysis.com/while.html) present in XML format. Currently, I am not handling function calls or recursion. I need to generate the control flow for this program.

A sample program (the numbers after the // indicate labels as generated by the parser):

```
begin

x:=1;        // 1
z:= 2+x;     // 2
x  := x+z;   // 3
y:=z-x+z;    // 4
w:=x+y+z;    // 5

while(not (y<z)) {   // 12
    x:=x+1;          // 6
    if (w <=x) {     // 9
        w:= w-x; // 7
    }
    else {
        w:=w+x;   // 8
    }
    z:=z-1;          // 10
    y:=y+1;          // 11
}

x:=z+y;              // 13
w:=x;                // 14

end
```

The AST for the aforementioned program is represented as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<program>
    <assignment label="1" variable="x">
        <value>
            <number value="1"/>
        </value>
    </assignment>
    <assignment label="2" variable="z">
        <value>
            <binary operator="+">
                <left>
                    <number value="2"/>
                </left>
                <right>
                    <variable name="x"/>
                </right>
            </binary>
        </value>
    </assignment>
    <assignment label="3" variable="x">
        <value>
            <binary operator="+">
                <left>
                    <variable name="x"/>
                </left>
                <right>
                    <variable name="z"/>
                </right>
            </binary>
        </value>
    </assignment>
    <assignment label="4" variable="y">
        <value>
            <binary operator="+">
                <left>
                    <binary operator="-">
                        <left>
                            <variable name="z"/>
                        </left>
                        <right>
                            <variable name="x"/>
                        </right>
                    </binary>
                </left>
                <right>
                    <variable name="z"/>
                </right>
            </binary>
        </value>
    </assignment>
    <assignment label="5" variable="w">
        <value>
            <binary operator="+">
                <left>
                    <binary operator="+">
                        <left>
                            <variable name="x"/>
                        </left>
                        <right>
                            <variable name="y"/>
                        </right>
                    </binary>
                </left>
                <right>
                    <variable name="z"/>
                </right>
            </binary>
        </value>
    </assignment>
    <while condition-label="12">
        <condition>
            <not>
                <binary operator="&lt;">
                    <left>
                        <variable name="y"/>
                    </left>
                    <right>
                        <variable name="z"/>
                    </right>
                </binary>
            </not>
        </condition>
        <body>
            <assignment label="6" variable="x">
                <value>
                    <binary operator="+">
                        <left>
                            <variable name="x"/>
                        </left>
                        <right>
                            <number value="1"/>
                        </right>
                    </binary>
                </value>
            </assignment>
            <if condition-label="9">
                <condition>
                    <binary operator="&lt;=">
                        <left>
                            <variable name="w"/>
                        </left>
                        <right>
                            <variable name="x"/>
                        </right>
                    </binary>
                </condition>
                <true-branch>
                    <assignment label="7" variable="w">
                        <value>
                            <binary operator="-">
                                <left>
                                    <variable name="w"/>
                                </left>
                                <right>
                                    <variable name="x"/>
                                </right>
                            </binary>
                        </value>
                    </assignment>
                </true-branch>
                <false-branch>
                    <assignment label="8" variable="w">
                        <value>
                            <binary operator="+">
                                <left>
                                    <variable name="w"/>
                                </left>
                                <right>
                                    <variable name="x"/>
                                </right>
                            </binary>
                        </value>
                    </assignment>
                </false-branch>
            </if>
            <assignment label="10" variable="z">
                <value>
                    <binary operator="-">
                        <left>
                            <variable name="z"/>
                        </left>
                        <right>
                            <number value="1"/>
                        </right>
                    </binary>
                </value>
            </assignment>
            <assignment label="11" variable="y">
                <value>
                    <binary operator="+">
                        <left>
                            <variable name="y"/>
                        </left>
                        <right>
                            <number value="1"/>
                        </right>
                    </binary>
                </value>
            </assignment>
        </body>
    </while>
    <assignment label="13" variable="x">
        <value>
            <binary operator="+">
                <left>
                    <variable name="z"/>
                </left>
                <right>
                    <variable name="y"/>
                </right>
            </binary>
        </value>
    </assignment>
    <assignment label="14" variable="w">
        <value>
            <variable name="x"/>
        </value>
    </assignment>
</program>
```

I need to generate the Control Flow of the program.

The control flow for the aforementioned program is like this:

```
1->2,
2->3,
3->4,
4->5,
5->12,
12->6,
12->13,
11->12,
6->9 ,
9->7,
9->8,
7->10,
8->10,
10->11,
13->14.
```

Note: while can have nested if statements and while statements in it and vice versa. I am preferably looking for a generic solution in Python/Java/C.

Thanks in advance,
Roy

Comment: Just an observation: I'm not sure you could have asked for help in a more diverse set of languages... Python: interpreted, and dynamically-strongly typed, Java compiled and statically-strongly typed, C compiled statically but relatively weakly typed... Totally not a criticism; in fact it's great because it means way more people can help, but it does make me curious what you're trying to do. :)

Comment: Umm...
Java: because a lot of developers I know swear by it
Python: because I think it's fun, and I am pretty sure, that the same snippet which Dan wrote would have translated to about 100+ lines of Java, including objects and classes.
C: because this was something which I learnt ages ago, and is relatively easy to read.

You can point out other languages like Scheme, Lisp, C#, but I think all of these fall under one of these categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. It returns the arcs in a slightly different order to your example, but that shouldn't matter.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
dom = minidom.parse('test1.wl.xml')


def print_arcs(from_list, to_list):
    '''
    Print arcs from every member of the from list, to every member of
    the to list
    '''
    for source in from_list:
        for target in to_list:
            print "%s -> %s" % (source, target)

def parse(node, came_from):
    '''
    Descend an XML structure representing an AST
    '''
    if not node:
        return came_from

    if node.nodeName=="#text":
        return parse(node.nextSibling, came_from)

    if node.nodeName=="program":
        return parse(node.firstChild, came_from)

    if node.nodeName=="assignment":
        this = node.getAttribute('label')
        print_arcs(came_from, [this])
        return parse(node.nextSibling, [this])

    if node.nodeName=="while":
        loop_start = node.getAttribute('condition-label')
        print_arcs(came_from, [loop_start])
        next = [loop_start]
        for s in node.childNodes:
            if s.nodeName=="body":
                loop_end = parse(s, [loop_start])
                print_arcs(loop_end, [loop_start])
        return parse(node.nextSibling, next)

    if node.nodeName=="if":
        if_start = node.getAttribute('condition-label')
        print_arcs(came_from, [if_start])
        next = []
        for s in node.childNodes:
            if s.nodeName=="#text":
                continue
            item = parse(s, [if_start])
            if item:
                next.extend(item)
        return parse(node.nextSibling, next)

    if node.nodeName=="condition":
        return None

    if node.nodeName=="true-branch":
        return parse(node.firstChild, came_from)

    if node.nodeName=="false-branch":
        return parse(node.firstChild, came_from)

    if node.nodeName=="body":
        return parse(node.firstChild, came_from)


parse(dom.firstChild, [])
```

This recurses through the structure of the AST, and its output depends on the type of node encountered. An assignment simply outputs arcs from the previous node(s) to the current node; an `if` needs arcs to the two possibilities, and a `while` needs arcs representing the loop and the possible fall-through. The code given keeps a list of where execution could have come from in order to end up at the current location. The `parse` function returns the location that ends the current block.

Note that the implementation of both `while` and `if` here is a bit hacky, and it will fall over on certain sorts of syntax error.

Comment: Dan! You're awesome! It worked perfectly! :D
How do I mark it as an useful answer, please help!
NOTE: Don't you think the label: 11-13 is not correct?

Comment: Good point! The termination of the while loop goes 11->12->13, so there shouldn't be a direct arc. I'll fix the code.

Comment: Do you think instead of writing #text, if you wrote ['binary', 'number','variable'] in a list of unwanted labels and then parsed it, would it be better?

Comment: I think the #text node is the representation in the XML DOM of the raw text between open and close tags -- in this case, it's always empty but we need to step over it when stepping through all of the nodes at a given level. The program never encounters variable/number/left etc. because they are at different levels of nesting from the items we're looking at -- so it would make no difference. Of course, if you wanted to extend this parser to do more interesting things, you would need to take them into account.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a virtual machine to execute this code.  Fortunately, all you have to deal with in this code is assignment, if and while statements.  You will also need your VM to keep a registry of variable names, which can be simply done with a Python dict. Start at the first statement, assignments just execute and proceed to the next.  if statements must evaluate the condition and then branch accordingly. while is similar to if, but you will need a stack of addresses to exit to when the condition evaluates false (use a stack to handle nested while's).  And keep track of the label numbers as you go.

Comment: Hi,
I have done a small dirty program which generates the code for programs without if/while.
    from xml.dom import minidom
    dom = minidom.parse('test1.wl.xml')
    assignments = dom.getElementsByTagName('assignment')
    numbers = [statement.getAttribute('label') for statement in assignments]

    #this works for programs without while/if
    for x, y in zip(numbers[:-1], numbers[1:]):
 print "%s --> %s" %(x, y)

    # finding parents
    for node in assignments:
 print node.parentNode.nodeName, node.getAttribute('label')

Can you show me a small snippet which handles while conditions?

Comment: I am also unable to understand the need for dict. I don't need to check for variables.

Comment: If you are going to map control flow, then you will need to evaluate the if conditions to see which path to take. To evaluate the if conditions, you'll need to know the values of the variables, so you can test the condition for true/false. Unless I have misunderstood what you call "control flow".

Comment: You will have to navigate the dom using the 'getChildNode', 'getSiblingNode' type calls - 'getElementsByTagName' will not preserve the nesting structure of if and while statements.

Comment: I would imagine the intention is to create the CFG via a simple static analysis, rather than to run the code, or use abstract interpretation, surely?

Comment: @Paul: Yep. You are correct! Can you please show me a small code-snippet that would do just the same?
snim2: Yes, you are correct as well!

Comment: @snim2: Oh, sure! "static analysis", need new glasses.  So no, the OP won't need the dict to track variable values.

Comment: Haha! Makes me feel like a puny dwarf among a bunch of python ninjas!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement a full VM to perform control-flow analysis. You do need to walk over the AST. Indeed the book mentioned by the site you linked to ([Principles of Program Analysis](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/~riis/PPA/ppa.html)) explains how to do this. Think about how each sort of statement in your language has entry and exit points. In a procedural language, an `if/else if/else` statement can be entered from the statement preceding it and may have several exit points (one for each branch of the `if/else if/else`). A `while` statement has an entry point from the statement preceding it, and two exit points - one exit that loops round to the top of the `while` and one which breaks out of the `while` and moves to the next statement. Assignment statements have one entry from the statement preceding the assignment and one exit point that leads to the subsequent statements.

This is the directed graph you need to draw. So, you want to iterate over the XML you have there "emitting" nodes in your CFG. The easiest way to do this, IMO is to use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), since you are writing in an OO language.

For example, this program:

```
begin
    x := 10          // 1
    if x < 100 {     // 2
        print "foo"  // 3
    }
    else {
        print "bar"  // 4
    }
end
```

would have the following CFG:

[image: CFG]

Comment: Thank you for the exaplanation snim2!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW if this is a homework question, please do label it as such.

Comment: Yes, and no. I am auditing this course! Just took it up as an exercise, but got horribly stuck.

No prior experience with these kind of flow analysis is probably the reason.

Comment: Ah, well the concepts are the important thing, the implementation should be straight forward once you understand everything ;)